# <? automatically converts to html comments

Tags: html, browser

see

```
<p>
 <? this is text;
</p>
```

it automatically converts to

```
<p>
<!--? this is text;
</p-->
</p>
```

in view source of browser while I run the file from file:/// url , so I am not able to get the output.

if i do not put the combination  **`<?`** , then it works fine,

can any body explain why ?

Comment: What is automatically converting it? Is that plain HTML file which your browser X is converting it?

Comment: yes it is plain html, and running in chrome or firefox

Comment: Looks like broken PHP opener to me

Comment: no @JamesNicholson . i have .html page, no php, and even  not ran from web server.

Answer (score 2):

In XML it represents a processing instruction, but `<?` is invalid in HTML. Conversion to a comment is just an attempt at error recovery.

Comment: May i ask why it is invalid? i have defined the doctype as html as well.

Comment: Presumably because it is a `<` character (which has a number of special meanings in HTML) followed by a `?` which doesn't match any of those special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers (not all browsers!) add the `<!-- -->` quotes aroud because it is invalid HTML.

`<` looks like a start for a HTML tag or `<?` a starting for PHP. There is no closingtag like `?>`.

Want to validate your website HTML? See the [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: first of all,
1) i have .html page and browse do not concern about php tag, it is a concern of web server,
2) even, pre tag will not help me, it can only done by html entities
3) and i am looking for why such beahviour

Comment: "because it is invalid HTML", you can't place random < in your site.

Comment: Please update your answer as it is not a solution for pre tag, ou can try even